# How much file size can iTextPDF can read?

Tags: java, android, itextpdf

I am having **Force Close** in my application, when i choose a file1(size: 33,016,510 - not sure if byte or kb) but when i try a file2(size: 604,612) it does not force close. **How much file size can iTextPDF can read?**

file1: 400-500pages, Has Image Background and Images, but Text are all **HIGHLIGHTABLE** so meaning text can be READ(This is how I determine if the contents of PDF are text or images, Correct me if i am wrong).

file2: 30-50pages, has images and no background.

I have ideas why it force closes.

1. Because of the PDF file size.
2. The Code it self.
3. The contents of the PDF.

The code i use to read PDF:

```
page_Content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(
                    reader, 0, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
```

**What's the problem here?**

Comment below if the information is lacking.

Exception:

```
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:123)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray.add(PdfArray.java:269)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readArray(PdfReader.java:1608)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPRObject(PdfReader.java:1657)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDictionary(PdfReader.java:1588)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPRObject(PdfReader.java:1624)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1143)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:511)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:170)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:159)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.example.panalyzerdemo.InformationRetrieval.pdfFilePath(InformationRetrieval.java:54)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.example.panalyzerdemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:207)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3514)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3560)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4644)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
12-26 19:20:19.026: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You really need to find out how big the file *actually* is. There's a huge difference between trying to read a 33MB file and a 33GB file.

Comment: @JohnSkeet so you are saying that the error was in the FILE SIZE? Is there a way to read that HUGE size?

Comment: @JohnSkeet isnt it a 33mb? file. its 33,243kb in my explorer.

Comment: Also note that a PDF file typically contains many streams that are compressed. When reading them for inspection or reuse, these streams need to be decompressed. This requires much more memory. In any case: there's a 2 GB limit for old iText versions and a 2 TB limit for the latest iText versions. If you get an OutOfMemoryException, the usual cause is that you didn't provide sufficient memory. That's not an iText problem, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with large PDF files. What I will do is NOT to read the whole PDF file but to read 50-100 pages first.

Comment: could you post an example of how you would you pass only 50 pages at a time through a `Reader`?